# How to have rollover state change on website logo

Tags: css, squarespace

I am currently using a squarespace template and am wondering how to inject a code that causes a rollover state change on my logo. All I want it to do is change to the neon green color that is a part of my theme when hovering over. The link to my website is www.henrykernsart.com

I have tried looking for a solution via squarespace and no one has helped me so far.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using custom css.  But, because squarespace templates tend to vary quite a bit, you will probably have to do a little research to figure it out.

There are a variety of ways to inject custom css into your squarespace site.  I'll illustrate 2 of them.

1. Affecting your entire site - In your squarespace admin dashboard, go to `Design -> Custom CSS`.  This will open a side panel with a large text box where you can enter css code.
2. Affecting just a single page - Open the page you want to be affected.  In the hierarchy panel of pages, hover over your page and you will see the gear icon.  Click on that to open the settings panel for the entire page.  Click on the `Advanced` tab and this will open a text box for css code.

The code you will enter will be the same in either place, with a small modification for the single page option.

You will need to know what your template calls your logo.  If you are lucky, your logo image will have it's own consistent id or unique class. (Looking at your site, you aren't lucky and yours doesn't.)  We can use that id or class to directly affect the image.

Let's say your image class was "Header-branding-logo" (that's what mine is).  Your code will look like this:

```
.Header-branding-logo:hover {
     content: url(https://the-url-to-your-alternative-logo-hosted-on-squarespace); 
}
```

That's if you are editing the css for the entire site.  If you are doing page-specific editing in the advance tab you have to enclose it in `<style></style>`:

```
<style>
.Header-branding-logo:hover { 
    content: url(https://the-url-to-your-alternative-logo-hosted-on-squarespace); 
}
</style>
```

If your logo has an id instead of a class, you can do the same, but instead of the class, you will use #id:

```
#block-a-bunch-of-id-numbers:hover{ ... }
```

If you aren't lucky enough to have your logo id'd, you will need to use a combination of Attribute Selectors and Complex Selectors.
First, find a valid, constant id or class.  BTW, this is an id that does **not** start with "yui-" or "block_yui-". Don't use ids that start with those.

On your website's template, you have a class called "logo-image".  That's probably a good place to start.  Starting from there you 'describe' the path to your image.

```
.logo-image >  a > img:hover{ ... }
```

Inside the `<div>` (marked with the 'logo-image' class) is an `<a>` and inside the `<a>` is your `<img>`.  So that's the path.

How do you get that path?  The easiest way for me is in chrome, right click on the logo image and choose "Inspect".  That will open the inspector from which you can examine your site's structure.

If you can't find a good class or id, you have the option of using an Attribute Selector.  Find a block somewhere above your image with a unique attribute.  Something like

```
data-content-field="site-title"
```

You can use that attribute as your anchor point.

```
[data-content-field="site-title"] > div > a > img:hover { ... }
```

Lots of ways to accomplish the task.  It's kind of fun to figure out.  (Remember, stay away from those "yui-" ids!)

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens when you hover the image is it swaps out the current code/image with new code/different image. That being said, in the css you need to specify the replacement. If the logo is a static image, I would recommend creating the logo using the hover color (in this case - neon green). Then set the hover event property to swap the default logo image with the hover image.

This link may help you with the :hover event property: [w3schools - CSS :hover selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)